# How to integrate Twilio MMS web hook in my java application

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I was working with twilio mms integration in my java application.i have some questions.
what will be the webhook request URL format?
how do I get the sender phone number?
how do I test it from the country other than US/Canda?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can read about what the Twilio request will look like here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application

Briefly, the request will be an HTTP `POST` request (by default, or you can change it to `GET`).

If it is a `POST` request, the body will be in the format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The request parameters will include things like `MessageSid` for the incomin message's ID, `Body` for the text body and `NumMedia` for the number of attachments. You can read the URL of each attachment from the `MediaUrl{n}` parameters, where "n" Is the index of the media. The sender phone number will be the `From` parameter.

To test this from outside the US I usually buy a second Twilio number and use it along with the API to send messages to my primary number.